# Mac OS Big Sur | kernal_task usage is 500% when connected to external monitor

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, display, big-sur, activity-monitor

I'm facing a system lag issue whenever I connect to my external monitor, even though there is no user process.

I have already gone through some of the answers in the stack exchange and did two things as of now.

1. I have disabled the automatic graphics switching.
2. I have disabled "Display have separate space"
3. There is no software update pending

as mentioned in this link [CPU usage is too high with Yosemite and an external monitor](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/193947/cpu-usage-is-too-high-with-yosemite-and-an-external-monitor)

But the problem, even after those two changes I can see kernal_task is more than 500% and I'm not able to use Macbook pro at all.

Previously it was once or twice an occurrence, now it is happening every time I connect to an external monitor.

[image]

Activity Monitor
[image]

[image]

I have also taken a spin-dump ( 5MB ) and system diagnostics ( 200+ MB ). So I dunno how to share this here. Let me know if any of you need it for analysis.

Answer (score 1):

This may officially seem like the strangest answer ever, but have you tried using the ThunderBolt ports on the right hand side of the MacBook Pro?

As per [this blog post](https://eclecticlight.co/2020/04/25/why-is-kernel_task-eating-my-cpu/), the thermal sensor in the MacBook Pro is located unhealthily close to the left hand side ThunderBolt ports, which will heat up and trip thermal throttling (the kernel_task spike you see), thus seriously hurting your user experience.

Comment: I have been using right thunderbolt ports only :)